after saving a png/jpg and after that pressing X to exit, why does GIMP ask for "do you want to save modifications?"
since i didn't modified anything since the manual saving.
why does it still asks for when i want to exit gimp?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You did modify it simply by opening the image. GIMP decompresses the image so it can be viewed and edited in GIMP.  When you then export as JPEG/PNG, GIMP recompresses the images for that format, When you then close the application, GIMP asks if you want to save the uncompressed XCF which is GIMP's native file format, just in case you need it in the future. You can click no if you don't think you'll need it.

Because if you did anything a wee bit advanced, like using multiple layers or creating a selection, you will lose that work is you don't save the image as XCF. This is why there are distinct "Save" and "Export" actions. Your fave word processor/spreadsheet does the same, if you export a PDF and exit it will ask if you really want to throw away the .DOC/.XLS.
Of course that may be seen as overkill if you just cropped the picture, but then there are simpler apps if your photo editing is basic.
